# Windows Phone heap size limit

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Does Windows Phone have a limit on the amount of heap memory an app can use?

Android has a heap limit of 24 mb. Does WP7 have a similar limit on heap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> An application must not exceed 90 MB of RAM usage, except on devices that have more than 256 MB of memory ...

For details check out technical certification requirements here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184840(v=VS.92).aspx